# JIRA Workflows and Schemes

Tags: jira

I am new to JIRA.

Can somebody explain to me the meaning of the different schemes in JIRA; like issue security scheme, notification scheme and so on?

Helpful online resources are also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A [notification scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme) maps email notifications to various events. For example: "When a defect is assigned, send an email to the assignee."

A [Field Configuration Scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme) maps Field Configurations to issue types.

A [Screen Scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+a+Screen+with+an+Issue+Operation) allows you to choose which Screen will be shown to a JIRA user when they perform a particular issue operation.

An [Issue Type Screen Scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+a+Screen+with+an+Issue+Operation) associates a Screen Scheme with issue types,

An [Issue Security Scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Issue+Level+Security) determines who can and cannot see issues.

A [Field Layout Scheme](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Field+Layout+Schemes+in+JIRA+3.x) allows you to configure which fields are visible and/or required fields for a given issue type on a per project basis.

For more details, check the [Jira documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Documentation).

Answer (score 3):

I really appreciate the detailed explanations available at "The Grey Blog":

http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/atlassian-jira-configuration-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Most parts of JIRA configuration can be set up differently for different projects. Some things, like custom fields, can be also set up differently for any pair of (project, issue type).

The schemes are the means to configure these per-project/per-type configuration pieces, with probably reuse of one configuration among different projects.

For example, issue security feature allows you to set up options for Security Level field and limit issue visibility to certain users based on the value of that field. Issue Security Scheme contains definitions of those options and how they limit issue visibility.

So you first configure Issue Security Scheme (may be more than one) to define that piece of configuration, and then you can assign each project one of the available Issue Security Schemes (or neither one), thus applying those pieces of config to the issues in that projects.

Answer (score 0):

Jira enables flexibility to customize issue types, fields, workflows, screens, permissions, security and notifications through schemes. You can create, assign and reuse these schemes to your projects based on your needs. These schemes are assigned to project's related schemes like plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

Notification scheme -- You can configure notifications like email for the issues you create or issues assigned to you and any change in status

Field Configuration scheme -- Scheme used to configure fields.. You can set based on project. You can add more fields and add to particular scheme. You can even set restrictions (lets say if it is mandatory field or not)

Permissions scheme -- Used to set permissions for the project. You can name like Admin or general user and give what they can do

Screen scheme -- Used to add fields for a particular screen.

Answer (score 0):

While others answered most of the points, I would like to throw some light on Issue Security Scheme.

This is the most versatile scheme where you can restrict accessing certain issues by the security level user has.

With combination of the permission groups and issue security features, you can do almost anything in Jira from a workflow point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Well schemes are sort of mapping entities.

They contain the units, like workflows,screens,issue types.

Schemes will define how a project decides which unit to use for which issue/operation.
This is of course a high level explanation.

Best bet is to start experimenting with 1 scheme, let's say screen scheme. Once you get the hang of the scheme entity, every other scheme will become understandable.